# How can I make call Kofax robot and run in Google apps script? ,using javascript and rest api

Tags: javascript, api, rest, google-apps-script, kofax

I've been trying to make robot run in google apps script from a Kofax robot management console, using rest api, but it doesn't work at all.

regardless of knowledge about Kofax, please find wrong part of my code.

I'm beginner at javascript, so I really glad if I cat get some advice about this problem.

```
function callKofaxRoboRestApi() {

var endpointUrl = '**rest api url**';

var requestParams = {
'username': 'my user name',
'password': 'my password'
};

const accessToken = "**my token**";

var headers = {
'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};

var options = {
'method': 'post',
'headers': headers,
'payload': JSON.stringify(requestParams)
};

var data = {
'entry': {
'group': {
'name': '**robot name**',
'type': 'robot'
}
}
};

var payload = JSON.stringify(data);

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(endpointUrl, options);
var responseData = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
Logger.log('success');
} else {
Logger.log('looser');
}
```

It return 'Exeption: Address unavailabl:https//rpa3.cm-system/...callkofaxRoboRestApi @kofax.documatation gs:38

Is there something wrong? or skipped code?

Comment: `https//rpa3.cm-system/...callkofaxRoboRestApi` is this url one of the variables in the script? should there be a colon after "https" - `https://...`

Comment: I think it is my rest api url